# Using weightSum with ScrollView

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I am new to Android.
I am stuck off in understanding the concept of using weight sum with weighted `LinearLayout`s. Have skimmed through a number of related questions on StackOverflow but still haven't found the solution.

**Scenario**
I have an activity layout page with number of components . The components are oriented vertically in the linear layout according to their layout_weights.

**Code**

```
<ScrollView fillViewPort="true" scrollBars="true">
<LinearLayout android:weightSum="150">
<!-- Various components present here each assigned layout_weight attribute
Total sum being 150 itself -->
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

**Question**

My question is that how can I use scroll View and weightSum together such that a total of `weightSum=100` displays on one page and for the rest 50 user needs to scroll down.

Answer (score 0):

This is the one idea how it could possible

```
 <LinearLayout weightsum="150" android:orientation="vertical">
      <LinearLayout layout_weight="100">
         //your LinearLayout 
      </LinearLayout>
      <ScrollView Layout_weight="50">
         //your scrollview layout
     </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html#attr_android:weightSum) says that the mission of `weightSum` is managing spaces below/under all the items of `LinearLayout`. Moreover, the weight does not purpose for specifying exact size of layout (but only for relative size), so nor for the paging. If you want to scroll `View`s page-by-page, you can use [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html).